# type narrowing on function that checks for nullish values

Tags: typescript

I have a codebase where, in several places, there are values that are passed around that I can't assert aren't nullish at the level of the typesystem, but that for debug reasons I need to be able to reliably check that aren't nullish at runtime.

I created the following function:

```
// Utility debug function that throws an informative error if any of the arguments
// are nullish, also reporting the caller
export function throwIfNullish(caller: string, args: Record<string, any>) {
  Object.entries(args).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null) {
      throw new Error(caller + " called with " + key + " = " + value);
    }
  });
}
```

which is used like this:

```
function someFn(a: string|undefined, b?: number|null): number {
    throwIfNullish("someFn", { a, b })
    // use a & b knowing they aren't nullish
}
```

However, TypeScript isn't able to perform type narrowing like it would be able to if I just checked something like `typeof a !== 'undefined'` inline.

Is there a way to have my function hint the typesystem that it can narrow down the type of the variables it gets passed?

Answer (score 0):

You need a generic function combined with a type predicate function which `asserts` the type of an argument.

That may look like this:

```
export function throwIfNullish<
  T extends Record<string, any>
> (
  caller: string,
  args: T
): asserts args is Required<T> {
  Object.entries(args).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null) {
      throw new Error(caller + " called with " + key + " = " + value);
    }
  });
}
```

This function is now generic over `T`, which must be an object type with string keys.

And it's return value is `asserts args is Required<T>`.

`asserts argHere is TypeHere` means that if the function does not throw then the following type is assumed to be correct.

`Required<T>` is the opposite of `Partial<T>` and removes `null | undefined` from all value types of an object.

Now you use that like so:

```
declare const data: { abc?: number } // mock a data object
throwIfNullish('test', data)
data.abc // number
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVxgCyggHcBJBAOSQBtrMBnfAHgCg44AVOUGYFAE3pwASsDTR+TejCiYUAcwA0cAIYoAngD4WmuAAo2cNCtrAoALjjTZCxYZVR59SxxYBKSyvr0zMIQ6c4BhFgAEckTChgSQ5dAG9DAHkAIwArMRgAOj4ZTGB6PQD6N0yEaABRFTR8PT0AbQBrYHVlADcTJGAAXTc4AF54w3ZMBH0YdTBgCFH26k7+vr64ACJUfmAEOWjluAAfXbhZ+cWllBpqXoT2a7xCEjgUYGI4cqgiKD1jUyg4AGoVowmajRODETAEAH-JrqP4ApY7f5HYBuADcQzgAF9DBjUSwsSx1mhqA5gEYcNI4PwVDAVJY4qpkmgAPyWM4AW2SZkxLAIRDIlHODBqAHJeNJhcoqTS3ATqSpMipGXAAPTKh5IDlmFhAA)